# Python 3 class attribute set contains == duplicate

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class "Plan'' that has an attribute "edges", which is a set.

For example:

```
Plan.edges

Out:
{Edge literal-b851-True-bel --0--> strut-23-b495,
 Edge strut-23-b495 --effect-of--> literal-8b06-True-at,
 Edge cam-step-shot-24-8734 --effect-of--> literal-b851-True-bel,
 Edge strut-23-b495 --effect-of--> literal-8b06-True-at}
```

Each edge has a source node, a string label, and a sink node.
Confused that I saw a duplicate, I let

```
edges = list(Plan.edges)

Out:
[Edge literal-b851-True-bel --0--> strut-23-b495,
 Edge strut-23-b495 --effect-of--> literal-8b06-True-at,
 Edge cam-step-shot-24-8734 --effect-of--> literal-b851-True-bel,
 Edge strut-23-b495 --effect-of--> literal-8b06-True-at]
```

and ask

```
edges[1] == edges[3]

Out:
True
```

It's my understanding that == operator is criteria for duplication (which I've customized using __eq__ hook). I've checked that the source and sink nodes are also equal via == operator. I also checked popping them out of the set and the == operator still found the edges to be equal. A simple fix is `Plan.edges = set(list(Plan.edges))` 
(this gives desired result) but I plan on running this over a million times so I'd prefer not to add unnecessary code, especially when I do not understand the root cause of the problem.

```
Edge.__eq__(e2, e4)
Edge.__eq__(e4, e2)
e2.__eq__(e4)
e4.__eq__(e2)
e2 == e4
e4 == e2
```

all return True.

My question is, how is this possible, and what can I do to prevent this? I'm running python 3.3.2. Thanks in advance for your help.

... in class Edge

```
class Edge:
__slots__ = 'source', 'sink', 'label'
def __init__(self, source, sink, label):
    self.source=  source
    self.sink = sink
    self.label = label

def __eq__(self, other):
        if other is None:
            return False
        if self.source.ID == other.source.ID and self.sink.ID == other.sink.ID and self.label == other.label:
            return True
        return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return (not self.__eq__(other))

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.source.ID) ^ hash(self.sink.ID) ^ hash(self.label)
```

Comment: You need to implement `Edge.__eq__`, not `Plan.__eq__`. If you did, show the implementation of `Edge.__init__` and `Edge.__eq__`.

Comment: Please reduce your original program to the shortest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: Do you alter any part of the edge's information after putting it into the set? For instance, if the `source` or its id changes, the hash will change and the set will no longer work correctly.

Comment: It's true that right before the error, I mutate either the source or the sink in the edge. If set duplication is based on \__hash\__ then this is the problem.

Comment: Removing the edge and then adding a new one fixes the issue. Thanks.

Comment: It will be better to just implement the \__hash__ method like:return hash((self.source.ID, self.sink.ID, self.label)).  you can do hash((x, y)) to avoid XORing yourself.